# How do I write a finder method that will return something at least a year old, but nothing if there is no such entry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, ruby-on-rails-5, finder

I'm using Rails 5 and PostGres 9.5.  I want to search my model for entries that are at least a year in the past and then return the most recent entry that is at least a year old.  If there are no such entries, I don't want to return any results.  I created this in my model ...

```
  def self.year_change(from_date)
    CryptoIndexValue.
          where('index_date > ?', from_date - 1.years).
          order(:index_date).
          take
  end
```

but when I call this with today's date, I get a result ...

```
 id | value |         index_date         |         created_at         |         updated_at
----+-------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  2 |     0 | 2017-07-30 15:51:52.118646 | 2017-07-30 15:51:52.147113 | 2017-07-30 15:51:52.147113
```

Notice that "index_date" in what is returned is just a few days ago.  How do I adjust what my finder method so that it will only return entries that are at least a year old otherwise not return any results?

Comment: But `index_date` *is* greater than a year ago... Maybe you don't want `index_date`s that are above a year ago. That's a hint.

Comment: I'm so stuck in my head, I'm not able to see what you're sayihng.  I see index date above as "2017-07-30 15:51:52.118646".  That seems within a year to me.  What are you referring to?

Comment: ... Is `2017-07-30 > 2016-08-08`?

Comment: Ah, ok so you're sayihng change "'index_date > ?'" to "'index_date < ?'".

Comment: I'm just asking questions :)

Answer (score 0):

I feel it's "unethical" to leave an answer to a question that should've been solved by now, and thus you shouldn't mark this as the right answer. But in case you haven't solved it already:

Year 2016 is smaller than 2017, therefor everything older than 1 year is smaller than everything created Today:

```
Date.today - 2.years <  Date.today 
=> true
```

Your code currently states the date the item was created as being larger than `-1.years`, which will return nothing because it's false.

So change:

```
where('index_date > ?', from_date - 1.years).
```

To:

```
where('index_date < ?', from_date - 1.years).
```